# Python function to add values in a Pandas Dataframe using values from another Dataframe

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, pandas, apply

I am a newbie in Python and I am struggling for coding things that seem simple in PHP/SQL and I hope you can help me.

I have 2 Pandas Dataframes that I have simplified for a better understanding.

In the first Dataframe **df2015**, I have the Sales for the 2015.
**! Notice that unfortunately, we do not have ALL the values for each store !**

```
>>> df2015

    Store   Date        Sales       
0   1       2015-01-15  6553        
1   3       2015-01-15  7016        
2   6       2015-01-15  8840    
3   8       2015-01-15  10441
4   9       2015-01-15  7952
```

And another Dataframe named **df2016** for the Sales Forecast in 2016, which lists **ALL** the stores.
( As you guess, the column **SalesForecast** is the column to fill. )

```
>>> df2016

    Store   Date        SalesForecast
0   1       2016-01-15      
1   2       2016-01-15  
2   3       2016-01-15  
3   4       2016-01-15  
4   5       2016-01-15
```

I want to create a function that for each row in **df2016** will retrieve the Sales values from **df2015**, and for example, will increase by 5% these values and add these new values in SalesForecast column of **df2016**.

Let's say *forecast* is the function I have created that I want to apply :

```
def forecast(store_id,date):
    sales2015 = df2015['Sales'].loc[(df2015['Store'].values == store_id) & (df2015['Date'].values == date )].values
    forecast2016 = sales2015 * 1.05
    return forecast2016
```

I have tested this function in a hardcoding way as below and it works:

```
>>> forecast(1,'2015-01-15')
array([ 6880.65])
```

But here we are where my problem is... How can I apply this function to the dataframes ?

It would be very easy to do it in PHP by creating a loop for each row in **df2016** and retrieve the values (if they exist) from df2015 by a **SELECT** and **WHERE Store = store_id and Date = date**.. ...but the it seems the logic is not the same with Pandas Dataframes and Python.

I have tried the *apply* function as follows :

```
df2016['SalesForecast'] = df2016.apply(df2016['Store'],df2016['Date'])
```

but I am unable to put the arguments correctly or there is something I am doing wrong..

I think I do not have the good method or maybe my method is not suitable at all with Pandas and Python.. ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are almost there! What's missing is the function, you've passed in the args.

The `apply` function takes in a function and its args. The documentation is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Without having tried this on my own system, I would suggest doing:

```
df2016['SalesForecast'] = df2016.apply(func=forecast, args=(df2016['Store'],df2016['Date']))
```

Comment: My apologies, I think the `broadcast` argument was unnecessary. I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice things about Pandas is that it handles missing data well. The trick is to use a common index on both dataframes. For instance, if we set the index of both dataframes to be the 'Store' column:

```
df2015.set_index('Store', inplace=True)
df2016.set_index('Store', inplace=True)
```

Then doing what you'd like is as simple as:

```
df2016['SalesForecast'] = df2015['Sales'] * 1.05
```

resulting in:

```
             Date  SalesForecast
Store                           
1      2016-01-15        6880.65
2      2016-01-15            NaN
3      2016-01-15        7366.80
4      2016-01-15            NaN
5      2016-01-15            NaN
```

That the `SalesForecast` for store 2 is `NaN` reflects the fact that store 2 doesn't exist in the `df2015` dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you just need to multiply the Sales column from df2015 by 1.05, you can just do so, all in df2015:

```
In [18]: df2015['Forecast'] = df2015['Sales'] * 1.05

In [19]: df2015
Out[19]: 
   Store        Date  Sales  Forecast
0      1  2015-01-15   6553   6880.65
1      3  2015-01-15   7016   7366.80
2      6  2015-01-15   8840   9282.00
3      8  2015-01-15  10441  10963.05
4      9  2015-01-15   7952   8349.60
```

At this point, you can join that result onto `df2016` if you need this to appear in the `df2016` data set:

```
In [20]: pandas.merge(df2016,      # left side of join
                      df2015,      # right side of join
                      on='Store',  # similar to SQL 'on' for 'join'
                      how='outer', # same as SQL, outer join.
                      suffixes=('_2016', '_2015')) # rename same-named
                                                   # columns w/suffix
Out[20]: 
   Store   Date_2016   Date_2015  Sales  Forecast
0      1  2016-01-15  2015-01-15   6553   6880.65
1      2  2016-01-15         NaN    NaN       NaN
2      3  2016-01-15  2015-01-15   7016   7366.80
3      4  2016-01-15         NaN    NaN       NaN
4      5  2016-01-15         NaN    NaN       NaN
5      6  2016-01-15  2015-01-15   8840   9282.00
6      7  2016-01-15         NaN    NaN       NaN
7      8  2016-01-15  2015-01-15  10441  10963.05
8      9  2016-01-15  2015-01-15   7952   8349.60
```

If the two DataFrames happen to have compatible indexs already, you can simply write in the result column to `df2016` directly, even if it's a computation on another DataFrame like `df2015`. In general though, you need to be careful about this, and it can be more general to perform the join explicitly (as I did above by using the `merge` function). Which way is best will depend on your application and your knowledge of index columns.

For more general function application to a column, a whole DataFrame, or groups of sub-frames, refer to [the documentation for this type of operation in Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#row-or-column-wise-function-application).

There are also links with some cookbook examples and comparisons with the way you might express similar operations in SQL.

Note that I created data to replicate your example data with these commands:

```
df2015 = pandas.DataFrame([[1, datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 6553], 
                           [3, datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 7016], 
                           [6, datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 8840], 
                           [8, datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 10441], 
                           [9, datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 7952]],
                          columns=['Store', 'Date', 'Sales'])

from itertools import izip_longest
df2016 = pandas.DataFrame(
    list(izip_longest(range(1,10), 
                      [datetime.date(2016, 1, 15)], 
                      fillvalue=datetime.date(2016, 1, 15))), 
    columns=['Store', 'Date']
)
```